# Jquery element.text() error "is not a function" when I use elements array

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am reading a XML file in which I have some p tags, and I want to to get each element text  "element.find()". But I got this error ".text is not a function".

This is the code I used:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: YQLurl,
                data: {
                    key: "value"
                },
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (reciviedXml){

                    for(var i = 0 ; i < $(reciviedXml).find('p').length;i++)
                    {
                      var paragraph= $(reciviedXml).find('p')[i].text(); 
                    }   
                });
```

I think my array is not an array of elements, or at least jquery can not unserestand it as elements list, what should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That will obviously won't work as `$(reciviedXml).find('p')[i]` will return a native DOM `Element` and there is no `text` method on the `Element`'s interface. Your code should work if you do `$(reciviedXml).find('p')[i].textContent;` although it would be extremely inefficient.

Here's a better way:

```
$(reciviedXml).find('p').each(function () {
    var paragraph = $(this).text();

    //do something useful with paragraph
    console.log(paragraph);
});
```

> I just want the 3rd tag text it gives me the error

You can also do `$(reciviedXml).find('p:nth-child(3)').text()` to get the text of the third paragraph directly.

You may also not use jQuery at all:

```js
var htmlString = '<p>1</p><p>2</p><p>3</p>';

var text = new DOMParser()
    .parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html')
    .querySelector('p:nth-child(3)')
    .textContent;

alert(text);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer works for me, and exactly is what I was looking for.